# Automounting vfat usb drive

Tags: debian, kde, usb-drive, automounting

I use debian 8 with kde-full package, everything is up-to-date.
I have 4 usb flash drives: all of them are formatted in Windows OS.
But only Sandisk "14.9 GiB Removable Media" is automounted correctly.
Trascend and KINGSTON are automounted in read only. I cannot do much using Dolphin.
So the problem is that these two drives are mounted with root as the owner.

What I have tried:
* playing with udev rules
  [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111685/usb-drive-permissions-when-automounting/124060#124060](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124060/122054)
  [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/automounting-usb-sticks-on-debian/186469#186469](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186469/122054)
  -- no result
* installing ntfs-3g, autofs, dosfstools packages
* running command sudo chown -R root:disk /media/usb1
  -- no success

I cannot believe that there is no way to make this working.
If ntfs usb drive is mounting correctly, there is the way to mount fat drive in the similar way.

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=febe762a-ce94-479e-957e-6f405012b81b / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660   user,noauto   0   0
/swap_debian    none    swap    swap    0     0
```

[image]

```
admin@debian-PC:~$ sudo fdisk -l
```

**Transcend:**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 30 GiB, 32224837632 bytes, 62939136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         256 62939135 62938880  30G  b W95 FAT32
```

**14.9 GiB Removable Media:**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b541b54

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 31266815 31264768 14.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

**KINGSTON:**

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.5 GiB, 8019509248 bytes, 15663104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x04030201

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2192 15663103 15660912  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Is not displayed:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.9 GiB, 4194304000 bytes, 8192000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6da2a859

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       63 4209092 4209030   2G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
```

The last on drive does not mount at all.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: I added output of     cat /etc/fstab